# Cardinality-wise, Is the amount of possible relations of x and y greater than or equal to the amount of possible functions of x?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Consider the set of all possible relations of $x$ and $y$ (under Real Numbers) $S_{xy}$.
The set of all possible functions of $x$, $S_x$, is therefore a subset of $S_{xy}$.

What is the cardinality of $S_{xy}$, $S_x$ and is $S_{xy}$ greater than $S_x$ or equal to it?

Answer (score 1):

Number of relations = $2^{|X×Y|}.$
Number of functions = $|Y|^{|X|}.$

What is your conclusion?

Comment: The number of functions should be $|Y|^{|X|}$ but that does not change the conclusion.

Comment: OP seems to be asking for a comparison of $x\times y$ and $x^x$ if i read the words, but then says $S_x \subseteq S_{xy}$?

Comment: $|X|$ and $|Y|$ are $\aleph_1$. Is $|X\times Y|$ equal to $\aleph_1$ or $\aleph_2$? Either way, is ${\aleph_1}^{\aleph_1}$ equal to $\aleph_2$ and is $2^{\aleph_2}$ equal to $\aleph_2$ or $\aleph_3$?

Comment: Use exponental laws.